# Module Programming: Node require() AND ES6 export

Tags: node.js, module, require, ecmascript-6, node-modules

So I want to program a module, but I want it to work with Node's `require`/`module.exports` system AND ES6 `export` keyword. I'm wondering if there is either

1. a conditional expression which would allow me to ascertain "Who is asking for this module, `require()` or `import`?" or
2. a way of implementing BOTH `module.exports` and `export` without Node@0.10+ freaking out about the `export` keyword.

This is primarily so my code is both compatible with current useable technology and will be backwards compatible after the ES6 switch later this year. Additionally, I am teaching my co-workers to program in JS and want to help them learn to make their code modular. Since we are so close to the ES6 switch, it would be easier to teach them one, mostly inclusive, way than teaching them 2 ways and requiring they just remember when to use each. If the answer is, "There is no way," I will just have to teach them one and add the other as a minor side note.

As always, Thank you all for any help you might provide. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: traceur options for modules https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Options-for-Compiling will compile to CommonJS, leaving the original ES6 modules intact.

Comment: This article http://www.mattgreer.org/articles/traceur-gulp-browserify-es6/ seems to do the trick.

Comment: There is still a google cached copy of this, 'Practical Workflows for ES6 Modules' Guy Bedford, 6 April 2014 (revised 20 July 2014), the domain seems to be down at the moment otherwise.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but the specification for loading modules from a JavaScript environment is still in its early days,  not something we are likely to be seeing as a standard in the near future?  [Ref. ES6 Module Loader Polyfill https://whatwg.github.io/loader/ ] 

Which leaves i) the AMD loader, ii) node modules + Browserify, or iii) scripts.  I'm tempted to hedge my vote with the latter (ease of testing and debugging, and deployment), the only reservation being the current lack of tools to transform to the former.

Comment: So I have been looking over the traceur information and I think it will be okay for modularization, but I don't think it will be good for the class I am leading. I am still reading the article by Bedford. I think I will just teach CommonJS `require`/`module.exports` method to the class and have the import/export functionality in ES6 as a small side note.

The ES6 spec is VERY near finalization and considering that this modular functionality is implemented all over now, I don't think that it is likely to change very much before June.

Comment: Additionally, [the article by Bedford](http://guybedford.com/practical-workflows-for-es6-modules) is up again and there is a [video of its materials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0VUjM-jJf2U)

Comment: `import` and `export` are to be found in the current draft, however it is the specification for loading modules from JavaScript (browsers, node, etc.) that as far as I can see is still quite a way from being a standard - ref. the link above to the ES6 Module Loader Polyfill (which is the wrong link for the polyfill btw, the correct one being https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader ).

Comment: The easiest route I would guess would be transcompiling to a node module, debugging with node debug and testing with nodeunit (with `browserify` for browser output as usual).  The more adventurous could configure a test framework to include the ES6 Module Loader Polyfill and load the modules transcompiled to `System.register()` functions calls (traceur `--modules=instantiate` option) with the loader API and `System` object (as described by the polyfill documentation).  The same steps being all it takes to run the code in a web page.

Comment: A good example of `browserify` in action btw converting CommonJS modules, https://github.com/montagejs/collections - ref. `collections.js`.  If I can add a note (disclaimer!) to the above as  well - I'm a complete newby to ES6 myself, and it's not an easy learning curve

Comment: I've just found myself penning the conclusion that I have personally (at least) arrived at: while the current ES6 draft specification includes modules, the JavaScript loader API (browsers, node, etc.) is currently still under development (though it is being prototyped) - ref. section 15 of the current ES6 draft for the module specification, the prototyped implementation of the loader is the ES6 Module Loader Polyfill, which links to the specification (that hopes some day to become a standard) that the polyfill is based on (linked to above as well).  If someone could check that over!

Comment: "there is also a new API being added to the language so you can programmatically import modules" JavaScript Modules the ES6 Way, Jack Franklin, 3 December 2014 http://24ways.org/2014/javascript-modules-the-es6-way/

Comment: ECMAScript 6 modules: the final syntax,  Dr. Axel Rauschmayer, 
2014-09-07  http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#importing_modules_and_loading_scripts

Comment: I'm with @user5321531 that writing es6-modules today and transpiling to es5 is the way to go. Babeljs (formerly 6to5) would be my best bet for transpiling to CommonJs style modules, see also http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/

Comment: I may end up doing that for my personal modules I want to be backwards compatible. As for the Class, I am just going to teach the CommonJS way and explain import/export in short.

Comment: Also, while learning Aurelia framework I found out about [jspm, Javascript Package Manager,](http://jspm.io/) a front end package manager which will manage the dependencies, use SystemJS to combine, and transpile (I think with babel) all of your code and dependencies at the same time. Additionally, it can pull from Github, Bower, and NPM for its sources. So for personal frontend this seems like the way to go. :D